# Regex to validate regex

Tags: regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Regexp that matches valid regexps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/362793/regexp-that-matches-valid-regexps)

Duplicate of [Regexp that matches valid regexps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/362793/regexp-that-matches-valid-regexps)

How do you produce a regex that matches only valid regex?

For instance: `"[hc]at"` would be valid (matching `"hat"` and `"cat"`), but `"[hcat"` would be invalid, as it is missing `]`.

Comment: Is strange that the original question got 26 up votes, and a duplicate question (by mistake) gets -2

Comment: @RaraituL: "Second place is just the first loser" - Dale Earnhardt - http://en.thinkexist.com/quotation/second-place-is-just-the-first-place-loser/1084714.html

Answer (score 2):

In general, no, because nested pairs of parens and brackets, etc., is something you need a recursive descendant parser (or similar) to handle.

Answer (score 2):

Use the right tool for the job. A better solution would be to use the RegEx class of the language you are using.

Something like:

```
>  Regex rx = new Regex("[INVALID REGEX
> HERE");  if(rx.Valid())  {    ...  }
```

Answer (score 1):

In Java you can check a regular expression by calling

```
// Create a pattern to match breaks
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[,\\s]+");
```

compile methode throws  PatternSyntaxException if the expression's syntax is invalid