# How to check if the string is a regular expression or not

Tags: java, regex

I have a string. How I can check if the string is a regular expression or contains regular expression or it is a normal string?

Comment: Maybe there is regular expression to check if a string is a regular expression. Interesting question! But i doubt that there is way that covers all possibilities.

Comment: is it impossible that a valid regex meant as _normal_ string?

Comment: Also relevant: ["Regex to validate regex"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/416532/regex-to-validate-regex)

Comment: I think the OP means, let's say he/she has `String s = "my string with \[.\] and another [^b].";` How does he/she know that the string contains regular expression? Am I right or am I right? lol

Comment: do you mean check if a string is a *valid* regular expression?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The only reliable check you could do is if the `String` is a syntactically correct regular expression:

```
boolean isRegex;
try {
  Pattern.compile(input);
  isRegex = true;
} catch (PatternSyntaxException e) {
  isRegex = false;
}
```

Note, however, that this will result in `true` even for strings like `Hello World` and `I'm not a regex`, because technically they are valid regular expressions.

The only cases where this will return `false` are strings that are not valid regular expressions, such as `[unclosed character class` or `(unclosed group` or `+`.

Comment: can i do something like filter all regex char from string and if the resulted string is equal to the original string the string is normal.

Comment: @Saurabh: you *could* do that, but "regex char" are just normal characters that can exist in a normal non-regex string as well. Parenthesis `()` are pretty common, `-` is used a lot as well, `+` and `*` can occur in anything that remotely touches on mathematics. `|` is somewhat rare, except in texts about coding. **Why** do you want to do that? Maybe that information can help us suggest an alternative approach.

Comment: @Joachim "The only cases where this will return false are strings that are not valid regular expressions" - I'm not sure this is the case. What about valid regex that do not have correct Java escapes i.e. '^\w+$'?

Comment: @hoipolloi: the "Java escapes" you talk about **only** exist in string literals. At the point where I have a `String` object they don't exist. So *either* I have a `String` representing `^\w+$` (possibly through a `String` literal that looks like this: `"^\\w+$"`) or I have a compilation error (by writing a `String` literal that looks like this: `"^\w+$"`). But there's no `String` object that "has wrong Java escapes". It's simply not possible.

Comment: Actually I have an input from user. I want to check if the input is a regular expression or normal input.

Comment: @Saurabh Kumar: is this for a search? Or something else? We need some context. Is the user *expected* to enter a regex? Or is he expected to enter normal text? Is both allowed?

Comment: it's for a  setting and the user can enter both with equal probabality.

Comment: @Saurabh: (I think that) hoipolloi is talking about the fact that within `String` literals (i.e. strings in your source code) you need to escape the backslash `\` because it has a special meaning. This can make regular expressions in Java source code look more complex than they actually are.

Comment: @Joachim ..."Java escapes"... Of course! My mistake; thanks for clarifying.

Comment: @Saurabh Kumar then what is the difference between them entering a regex and a normal string.  What will you do differently once you know which the string is?

Comment: @Saurabh: in that case there are two sane solutions: define whether the setting is a regex and stick to it (i.e. allow only a regex *or* allow only a non-regex) *or* provide an additional setting that toggles if the string is interpreted as a regex or not. Guessing won't help you here.

Comment: but what i would do java escape on string and check if the normal string is now equal or not to the original string..? will that work

Comment: @Saurabh Kumar, forget the mention of "java escapes" they are not going to help you at all, and were only mentioned in error

Comment: @Saurabh: **NO!** There is no way to read the users mind! Is `[^abc]` a regex? Or is it a literal string because I want to **search** for that regex?

Comment: @Saurabh Kumar, again, what are you going to do with the regex and what are you going to do with the 'normal' string?  how is this different.  knowing this will help people decide what the best option for you is.

Comment: no no...there is a way....I will do query = query.replaceAll(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g, "\\\$&"); and now if it conatins regex it will not equal to the normal query ,and if yes it conatins regex. :)

Comment: So `"ä"` is a regex? And `Something; or another` is a regex? Also: you seem to post JavaScript code, not Java code.

Comment: if you won't tell us your intention then we cannot help you any more.  I suspect that your approach is doomed to failure.

Comment: @Saurabh: then more power to you, but I agree with @Sam and assume that you only postponed the real problem.

Answer (score 4):

This is ugly but will detect simple regular expressions (with the caveat they must be designed for Java i.e. have the relevant back-slash character escaping).

```
public boolean isRegex(final String str) {
    try {
        java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(str);
        return true;
    } catch (java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: can i do something like filter all regex char from string and if the resulted string is equal to the original string the string is normal.

Answer (score 2):

there is no difference between a 'normal' sting and a regular expression.  A regular expression is just a normal string which is used as a pattern to match occurrences of the pattern in another string.

As others have pointed out, it is possible that the string might not be a **valid** regular expression, but I think that is the only check you can do.  If it is valid then there is no way to know if it is a regular expression or just a normal string because **it will be a regular expression**

It is just a normal string which is interpreted in a specific way by the regex engine.

for example "blah" is a regular expression which will only match the string "blah" where ever it occurs in another string.

When looked at this way, you can see that a regular expression does not need to contain any of the 'special characters' that do more advanced pattern matching, and it will only match the string in the pattern

Comment: Maybe he means a valid regular expression?

Comment: @Jeff, maybe.  if so hopefully he will edit the question to indicate that, and then I'll delete the answer, as it won't make much sense in that context.

Comment: can i do something like filter all regex char from string and if the resulted string is equal to the original string the string is normal.

Comment: what do you mean 'regex char'?  all chars are regex chars, but some have special meaning to the regex engine in certain situations in the pattern when the string is used as a regex pattern

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you'd try to compile that regular expression using regexp package from Apache ( http://jakarta.apache.org/regexp/ ) and, if you get an exception then that's not a valid regexp so you'd say it's a normal string.

```
boolean validRE = true;
try {
    RE re = new RE(stringToCheck);
} catch (RESyntaxException e) {
    validRE = false;
}
```

Obviously, the user would have typed an invalid regexp and you'd be handling it as a normal string.

Comment: can i do something like filter all regex char from string and if the resulted string is equal to the original string the string is normal.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone just want to distinguish just plain text strings and regular-expressions:

```
static boolean hasSpecialRegexCharacters(String s){
    Pattern regexSpecialCharacters = Pattern
            .compile("[\\\\\\.\\[\\]\\{\\}\\(\\)\\<\\>\\*\\+\\-\\=\\!\\?
      \\^\\$\\|]");
     return regexSpecialCharacters.matcher(s).find();
}
```

Answer (score -3):

```
/**
 * If input string is a regex, matches will always return a false.
 */ 
public boolean isRegex(final String str) {   
    return str != null ? !str.matches(str) : false;
}
```

Comment: The string `x` is a valid regex that matches itself, so your code doesn't work correctly.

Comment: x.* matches x.* as well so I think it doesn't even work to differentiate between regular string and string with regex symbols