# How to check if a string is a valid regex in Python?

Tags: python, regex, string, validation

In Java, I could use the following function to check if a string is a valid regex ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6341367/how-to-check-if-the-string-is-a-regular-expression-or-not)):

```
boolean isRegex;
try {
  Pattern.compile(input);
  isRegex = true;
} catch (PatternSyntaxException e) {
  isRegex = false;
}
```

Is there a Python equivalent of the `Pattern.compile()` and `PatternSyntaxException`? If so, what is it?

Comment: Wouldn't any string be a valid regular expression? I could be wrong

Comment: @Haidro no, think of missing brackets and illegal use of special characters

Comment: @RobinKrahl Ah, touché ;)

Comment: is there a way i can use `try...except` and `re.compile` in python? will the `re.compile` validate regex?

Comment: @alvas Why don't you try it?

Comment: @hcwhsa, because i can't think of a valid but complex regex that might slip through `re.compile`. hahahhaa

Comment: @alvas Something like `re.compile("(" * 1000 + "a" + ")"*1000)` will fail with `RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded` instead of `re.error`

Answer (score 104, accepted):

Similar to Java. Use [`re.error`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.error) exception:

```
import re

try:
    re.compile('[')
    is_valid = True
except re.error:
    is_valid = False
```

> exception `re.error`
>
> Exception raised when a string passed to one of the functions here is
>   not a valid regular expression (for example, it might contain
>   unmatched parentheses) or when some other error occurs during
>   compilation or matching. It is never an error if a string contains no
>   match for a pattern.

Comment: @alvas, As long as you're using [Regular expression supported by Python](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax).

Comment: This is OK for regex syntax errors, but mind also `TypeError` if the pattern is not a `str`.

Comment: And also `RecursionError` for regexes similar to [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19630994/how-to-check-is-a-string-is-a-valid-regex-python#comment29145368_19630994). It can also be raised for invalid regex, for example `'('*1000+'a'+')'*1000+'('`.

Comment: @TomaszGandor, user202729, Thank you for the comment.

Comment: nevertheless, `string{data}` is valid regexp

Comment: @Belegnar, As previously commented, "As long as you're using Regular expression supported by Python.", BTW, I didn't know `string{data}` is a valid regexp. Thank you for the information (thumbup)

Answer (score 4):

Another fancy way to write the same answer:

```
import re
try:
    print(bool(re.compile(input())))
except re.error:
    print('False')
```