# Validate regex with Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I was wondering if there is a way of testing if a regular expression inputted is valid in JavaScript.

Something like

```
if ( isValidRegexp($("#regexp")) {
...
}
```

I don't need a regex like this question [Regexp that matches valid regexps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/362793/regexp-that-matches-valid-regexps)

Comment: I dont think I have ever seen invalid Regex, are there some characters that are not valid?

Comment: Incorrectly nested brackets for example are considered to be invalid regex.

Comment: @martin: I don't know what exactly musefan had in mind, but I'm certain that depending on its contents, a FOO is either a Regex or not-a-Regex, i.e. for me, improper nesting of brackets makes not-a-Regex :) Therefore we can argue about "ever seeing invalid Regex" :))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create this function like this:

```
function isValidRE(str) {
   var isValid=true;
   try {
      var re = new RegExp(str, "g");
   } catch(err) {
      isValid=false;
   }
   return isValid;
}

console.log(isValidRE("\d")); // true
console.log(isValidRE("(\d")); // false
```

#### Live Demo: http://ideone.com/9z2UKW

Comment: Chose this answer because it is a function, but what is the "g" for?

Comment: g was for global, not really needed in this case and you can omit it.

Answer (score 2):

OK, so it is pretty easy. You just create a new RegExp object and catch the error:

```
try{
   var r = new RegExp("my regex string");
}
catch(e){
    //regex is invalid
}
```

[Here is a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/xrjPP/)