# Defining a RegEx Type in JSON Schema

Tags: json, regex, types, schema

I am looking for an *elegant* way of checking that a value is a valid regular expression in a JSON schema. So far I have been content with requiring a `string` type:

```
{
    "pattern": { "type": "string" }
}
```

I would like to make my check more strict and see that `pattern` is a valid regular expression:

```
{
    "definitions": {
        "regex": {
            ??? #not another regex -- that was already disproved
        }
    }

    "pattern": { "type": "regex" }
}
```

By *valid* I mean checking that there are no syntax errors in the regular expression, such as open parentheses and so on.

I thought for a while that one of the possible solutions was a regex that would match a regex, but I was shown this was already discussed for instance in [Regexp that matches valid regexps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/362793/regexp-that-matches-valid-regexps), turning out that such an approach was impossible. What **other** ways are there?  I can think of a few directions this could lead, but could not find any information. Can I have the schema validator, for instance, somehow compile the regex? Do some validators support a `regex` primitive type unofficially? Is it in line to become a primitive type in JSON Schema v5, or some standard extension? Can I ``shell out'' of the schema and make the check? Or anything else?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regexp that matches valid regexps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/362793/regexp-that-matches-valid-regexps)

Comment: Sorry but I do not think this is a duplucate. I am looking for checking a regex in a JSON schema and checking with another regex was *one* way I could imagine, but I'm equally interested if there are others (all the more since the referenced question basically says doing it with regex is impossible).

Comment: The accepted answer states *simply try to compile it with whichever programming language or regular expression library you're working with* i.e. not impossible, however not trivial. If there's something else you're asking for, it's not clear to me ;)

Comment: Yes. How dow do you say that in JSON schema?  (Shema being the key word here.)

Comment: If I understand well you want to validate the format : 
   `"definition" : { "regex" : { "a simple regex" } }`
And then to validate what I call `a simple regex`. Is that right ?

Comment: No, the "definition" is just a suggestion that a "regex" type could be somehow defined. What I want to validate is `"pattern": { "type": "regex" }` wherever the `regex` type comes from.

Comment: Well, I simply want to check if a value is a valid _regex._ I don't want to be limited to "simple" regular expressions -- that would be too limiting for my users. Somehow Defining the `regex` type myself is one of the options I'm exploring.

Answer (score 0):

Then I'd have to agree with what's said in [Regexp that matches valid regexps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/362793/regexp-that-matches-valid-regexps) - **It's not possible**.

However, I guess you could limit the complexity of the allowed regex, e.g. in it's most limited way maybe `\.\*` only allowing the regex `.*`, up to more complex, but still simple, constructs. Like

```
^(?:(?:[.\w\s]|\\w|\\d|\\s)(?:\*|\+|{\d+(?:,\d*)?})?)+$
```

allowing things like `.*` as well as `prefix\d+postfix`, `\w{1,3}\d+`, and so on...

(This was meant as a comment, but could be a possible answer, so... ;)

Regards

Comment: There is no need, hower, to get fixated on a regex-based solution. That was just one of the possible approaches!